# How to import enum

Tags: macos, python

I installed Python 3.4.1 on my Mac (OSX 10.9.4), and I need to work with enums.
I started to write a script in a text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from enum import Enum
```

And from the terminal:

```
chmod 0700 myscript.py
./myscript.py
```

But I get the following error:

```
from enum import Enum
ImportError: No module named enum
```

At the same time, if I use IDLE I have no problem with the command:

```
from enum import Enum
```

How can I use enum from a script file?

EDIT:

If I `echo $PYTHONPATH` nothing is printed. While following is the output of `print(sys.path)`:

```
['/Users/Marco/Desktop/scripts', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

I can see that the first path corresponds to the directory where `myscript.py` is located, also it seems that it is used the 2.7 version of python, even if I just installed the last version (3.4.1).

Comment: Have you made sure the path to the python Libraries/modules is in your search path?

Comment: @Fegnoid How? I have not any troubles to run other scripts, or even import other modules (math, tkinter, ...).

Comment: on a terminal type `echo $PYTHONPATH` that will display where python is looking for stuff when called from a script, and then start idle `import sys` and then `print sys.path`.  please add those to your question

Comment: @Fegnoid please see my edit.

Comment: can you do `python -V` and tell me what version it thinks it is using. it may be that you need to change the default version of python in use. and try run the script with `python3 myscript.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace your first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

with the following one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This should work for you.
The former is hardcoded to always run `/usr/bin/python`, while the latter will run whichever python would be default in your current environment (try `echo $PATH`).

Please refer also to the following answers:

[What's the difference between these two python shebangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709616/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-python-shebangs)

[Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script/2429517#2429517)